# High percentage of IO in iotop

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, io, mongodb

I have a problem with a very slow process (mongod), so I downloaded `iotop` to see how is my drive going.

I can see a very high percentage in the `IO<` column, constantly about 70-99%. Can someone please explain to me what does it mean?

Do I understand it correctly that this means that the process is almost always waiting for I/O operations to be finished, which implies that my disc is basically incredibly slow? And could there be any other solution than just buying a better drive?

Comment: what kind of disk is it (mechanical or SSD) and what kind of bus is it attached on (Sata, PCI-E, USB)? since this is a DB process, yes it can swamp IO if the performance is not properly balanced by an experienced server admin and DBA. see here for more info on what IOTop is telling you: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/282225/how-does-iotop-calculate-the-relative-i-o-activity

Comment: I am working on a virtual machine. I need to ask the guy who manages it, but my guess is that it is definitely a mechanical disk. Could you explain what do you mean by the "performance is not properly balanced by an experienced server admin and DBA"?

Comment: DB servers are perhaps the most carefully managed systems in the data-center. if you had asked 5 years ago, everyone would be telling you not to put a DB server on a VM. they have improved a bit in that time, but the tuning of your database indexs, statistics, execution plans, and of course planning for hardware contention are all key. only one command can be processed by a disk at once, so putting two high-use/high-IOPs DBs on the same disk is a recipe for slow running apps.